# Visual Studio 2019 Extremely Slow When Loading Resources

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, cocossharp

I'm having trouble in visual studio 2019 debug mode while loading CocosSharp assets. It was working until the last update. (my current version: Community 16.2.5). Can you help me please?

I load my resources like this:

```
var cache = CCTextureCache.SharedTextureCache;        
cache.AddImage("image1");
cache.AddImage("image2");
```

In release mode everything is normal, but debugging on android is extremely slow when loading these assets.

what I already did:

Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General

disabled -> Enable diagnostic tools during debugging

Comment: Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to make the microsofties aware of your trouble so they can fix it.

Comment: thanks, I will do as advised.

Comment: Don't hold your breath waiting for a response.  Microsoft probably knows it's slow and their feedback site is just a catch all.

Comment: thanks for answering. I'm using vs17. is free of this problem